# Spring-boot data auto populate nosql database

Tags: spring-boot, automation, nosql, spring-data-mongodb

When working with springboot data in relational databases, if you place schema.sql and data.sql in classpath it does populate into relational database automatically.

Is there a similar approach for nosql databases like mongo ?

Any direction is welcomed.

Comment: [mongock](https://mongock.io) could be an option